# Symfony2 Include Custom Configuration Variables

Tags: php, symfony, config

I'm using Symfony2 to access an API. I have a controller that initializes the Oauth and another that is for the Callback. Instead of manually typing out the api key, and other variables into these controllers, I want to have a single "configuration" file that I can include in all relevant locations (ie, the Oauth controller and OauthCallback controller).

How do I go about doing this? Should I add more lines to the `config.yml` or should I just create a new file called `config.php` and include it? With normal ol' php it'd be an easy `require_once` but since this is a framework, I want to make sure I'm doing it the "right" way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameters in `parameters.yml` or `config.yml` file.

```
parameters:
    my_api_key: 1234
```

In controller get like that:

```
$apiKey = $this->container->getParameter('my_api_key');
```

Comment: Do I need to `use Symfony\...` of some kind in order for `$this` to work? Or can I simply access `$this` anywhere in the Symfony framework?

Comment: In controller you can use `$this` if you extending base controller, in services you can inject parameters as arguments (or whole container). `$this` is just the actuall instance of class.

Comment: Ah, okay, my controller is like `class OauthController extends Controller` so it should work then!

Comment: Just a comment that if you put it in the parameters file, make sure you put it in `parameters.yml.dist` instead of `parameters.yml` since the latter is generated from `parameter.yml.dist` and you don't want it to be overwritten whenever it is regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should write it in the config.yml. Remember that you can write other parameters and include it in the main config.yml with

```
imports:
    - { resource: mi-file.extension}
```

In the controller, you can get this parameters with

```
$var= $this->container->getParameter('name_parameter');
```